# Fill Remaining Hight with Scrollable Div

Tags: css

So I've tried multiple solutions, but none seem to be working for my layout. What I'm hoping to have is 2 columns, each with 2 divs occupying 100% of the parents width. The height of each div is variable based on content.

So the idea is, the 2 columns on the left will determine the height of both columns, and the last div (in the bottom right) will be scrollable and occupy the remaining space.

I have an example in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Split98/cndej/ but there are 2 problems with this:
a) It doesn't allow for div C to still be dynamic in height
b) I really don't want to use display:table-cell

Also, when I tried implementing this temporary solution to my site everything broke anyway. So instead of trying to fix something I don't really even consider a solution I'm tossing in the towel and asking for help.

Now I know there are TONS of questions about equal height, but I couldn't find a way to solve both my problems: have left and right divs the same height, and have all 4 divs occupy the space.

So at it's most basic form (and again, I'm hoping to accomplish this without table-cell if possible):

```
<div id="wrap">
 <div class="left">
   <div class="A">A</div>
   <div class="B">B</div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="D">Need this to expand to fill</div>
 </div>
</div>


.left {
 width: 200px;
 display: table-cell;
}

.right {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 display: table-cell;
 background: yellow;
} 

.A {
 background: blue;
 height: 100px;
}

.B {
 background: pink;
 height: 200px;
}

.C {
 background: red;
 height: 50px;
}

.D {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 top: 50px;
 right: 0px;
 background: green;
}
```

I'm also not opposed to using Javascript, but I'm not very strong at all with it. Preferably, if it's possible, I'd like to do this with CSS.

Thanks guys!

Comment: there are lots of questions about this. and the answer is "no, you can't do this without javascript". http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fill+remaining+height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If choose JavaScript, you can use this solution with jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $('.D').height( $('.right').height() - $('.C').height() );
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cndej/3/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot guys. Fully working with js now, and looking great!